# Laravel - How do i use the Return value of a controller in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, controller

I have no specific code sample as this is just out of interest but:
How would i use the return value of a controller method , let's say

```
public function example() {
     return->back()->with('success');
}

public function exampleTwo() {
     return 'failed';
}
```

in the blade from which i called this function with:

```
<a href="URL TO ROUTE(which calls controller method)">
```

to, for example, change the color of the a tag?
i'd know how to do it using ajax but not using this return val as this route is called via the html -> routes -> controller @ method
and not via ajax -> url -> return

I hope you could kind of follow :) if not i will specify the question in more depth but i guess its quite clear what i want.
Thanks for helpin' me out!

Comment: The only way to use a return value is **a)** Use an ajax request to get json back. **b)** Write the value to a javascript variable before sending the page to the user. `let val = "<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a URL like,

`Route::get('/target/url', 'myController@myMethod');`

Your method `myMethod` in controller `myController` will be like,

```
public function myMethod() {

  return "myValue";

}
```

Now, You need to call this as ajax request, *(Here I am using jQuery Get)*

```
$.get( "target/url", function( data ) {
  var x = data; // var x = 'myValue'
});
```

Comment: you can do something like: `$estates = Est::query()->get(['est_id', 'est_name', 'est_sigla']);  return view('admin/states/index', ['estates' => $estates]); `

Comment: He needs to re-use the response in Javascript

Comment: he can to get in view... `var t = <?= json_encode($estates) ?>`